# Eclipse Luna without built-in plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

Eclispse Luna has been just released. I wanted to grab it from the [download site](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php?release=luna). But here comes my problem. Even the Standard and Java Developer versions have features built-in which are not needed for me and just slows down the IDE. For example i do not use Mylin or Plug-in development. These things cannot be deleted from the installation... Is there an Eclipse Luna release which only contains the basic package?

Comment: Just FYI, plug-ins that are installed but never invoked by the user do *not* generally affect the performance of Eclipse. Eclipse uses a lazy-loading architecture that will only load a plug-in if/when some feature of it is invoked. It *is* possible for a plug-in to register to be loaded on start up, but that's widely discouraged and very few eclipse.org plug-ins do that (and only very carefully).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the Eclipse Project [downloads](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.4-201406061215/)

The Eclipse Platform is the smallest (but does not even have Java development).

The Eclipse SDK has Java and Plugin development and the Eclipse source. This is the one I always start from.

Comment: [Platform Runtime Binary](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.4-201406061215/details.html#PlatformRuntime) doesn't have associated source but [Platform SDK](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.4-201406061215/details.html#PlatformSDK) has it. But it is NOT available to download [Any where here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.4-201406061215/). Where we will get **Platform SDK[NOT SAME AS ECLIPSE SDK]**?

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK I don't know of a download but it is available in the `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4` update site